# How to link or reference a Rectangle to an Image in Xaml for access in C# code behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am learning XAML/C# while working on a Windows Universal App.

The program allows a drag and drop of an image over a chessboard, which is a grid with 8 rows and 8 columns. Each grid cell has a Rectangle and an Image. The drag and drop works, dragging an Image to an Image. Upon a drag start event and upon the drop event, the C# code behind gets the image source (on the drag start event) and the image target (on the drop event).  Both the source and the target are available as the sender parameter for the start drag event and the drop event.  No problems with this.  I would also like access, in the C# code behind, the Rectangle which is in the same grid cell as the Image, as shown in the following XAML code.

Is there a way to add a property to the XAML code for the Image, to reference the Rectangle in the same grid cell?

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding Source={StaticResource queenModel0}, Path=Color, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Image Name="Image0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="{StaticResource imageSource}" Tapped="OnImageTapped"  AllowDrop="True"
   CanDrag="{Binding Source={StaticResource queenModel0}, Path=HasQueen, Mode=TwoWay}"
   Opacity="{Binding Source={StaticResource queenModel0}, Path=Opacity, Mode=TwoWay}"
   DragEnter ="Image_DragEnter" DragLeave="Image_DragLeave" DragOver="Image_DragOver" DragStarting="Image_DragStarting" DropCompleted="Image_DropCompleted" Drop="DropQueen" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of at least two possible approaches:

**Option #1:**

Retrieve the `Rectangle` by row/column index:

```
int row = Grid.GetRow(sender), column = Grid.GetColumn(sender);
Rectangle rectangle = GetChildForRowColumn<Rectangle>(grid1, row, column);
```

where:

```
T GetChildForRowColumn<T>(Grid grid, int row, int column)
{
    foreach (Rectangle child in grid.Children.OfType<T>())
    {
        if (Grid.GetRow(child) == row && Grid.GetColumn(child) == column)
        {
            return child;
        }
    }
}
```

**Option #2:**

Bind the `Tag` property to the related `Rectangle` object:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect20" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding Source={StaticResource queenModel0}, Path=Color, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Image Tag="{x:Reference Name=rect20}" Name="Image0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="{StaticResource imageSource}" Tapped="OnImageTapped"  AllowDrop="True"
   CanDrag="{Binding Source={StaticResource queenModel0}, Path=HasQueen, Mode=TwoWay}"
   Opacity="{Binding Source={StaticResource queenModel0}, Path=Opacity, Mode=TwoWay}"
   DragEnter ="Image_DragEnter" DragLeave="Image_DragLeave" DragOver="Image_DragOver" DragStarting="Image_DragStarting" DropCompleted="Image_DropCompleted" Drop="DropQueen" />
```

Then in your code-behind:

```
Rectangle rectangle = (Rectangle)((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag;
```

There are probably other ways to accomplish the same, but the above seem reasonable straightforward to me.

Comment: Your option #2 will not work because my Visual Studio project is a Windows Universal Program (tagged here as uwp [universal windows platform]).  Visual Studio reports this error, "Reference is not supported in a Windows Universal Project."   I did, however, get a variant of your option #1 to work.

Comment: @Mike: fair enough. I don't recall off the top of my head what the syntax for a reference in UWP would be. I'm sure it has the capability, but I do often run into these sorts of arbitrary syntactical differences between the various XAML incarnations (never mind the _functional_ differences, which of course are much more frustrating).